# mobile view: Logo second word not in new line

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image: here is sony xperia z2 mobile view.]

attached Image of mobile view problem.  this website used different letter color jQuery.  I also get jQuery code from stackoverflow, and this website also in wordpress. and the **SCRIPT SCALE both words i put in title Tag**. I need to putt SCALE word in new line,  is that possible?  i see in my Sony Xperia Z2 mobile. This website built-in bootstrap. If anyone need different letter color jQuery i will attach. Thanks in advance. **One More Thing: when i visit the website in Mozilla developer mobile view then all showing GOOD. but in my mobile get this problem**

i also used:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

and

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

[here is main online website link:](http://www.scriptscale.com/)

i used jQuery code in head tag:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('.protein').each(function() {
    var target = $(this).html();
    target = target.split("");
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0, len = target.length; i < len; i++) {
        result += '<span class="' + target[i] + '">' + target[i] + '</span>';
    }
    $(this).html(result);
   });
});
```

and CSS code:

```
.S { color:#fff;}
.c { color:#e21735;}
.r { color:#37a647;}
.i { color:#32b9e9;}
.p { color:#f85b3a;}
.t { color:#084e7f;}
.a { color:#c9db47;}
.l { color:#e43794;}
.e { color:#c749f0;}
```

and wordpress title code is :

```
<h1 class="cover-heading"><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> | <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>"><span class="protein"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></span></a></h1>
```

Also See this that i used the code in my Script Scale wordpress theme:

http://codepen.io/scriptscale/pen/vyJGWZ

Comment: your current working code related to the problem please

Comment: Jquery code? Or css code?

Comment: `Css` most probably

Comment: i checked css code, but i didn't detect any problem!!

Comment: first of all did you set `word-wrap`? and secondly `when i visit the website in Mozilla developer mobile view then all showing GOOD. but in my mobile get this problem` mozilla dev tools does its best to emulate a mobile screen but the end result will still be different, i mean no matter how much a duplicate iPhone looks like the original in the end its still a fake right?

Comment: i give the `word-wrap`, but still same problem

Comment: can i give my website link adress in main post? for anyone view on mobile?

Comment: yes please do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh ok after adding your'e code i understand a little bit about whats going on

wrap the spans in another span tag, some what like this

```
<span class="protein">
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <span class="S">S</span>
        <span class="c">c</span>
        <span class="r">r</span>
        <span class="i">i</span>
        <span class="p">p</span>
        <span class="t">t</span>
    </span> 
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
        <span class="S">S</span>
        <span class="c">c</span>
        <span class="a">a</span>
        <span class="l">l</span>
        <span class="e">e</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

---

**EDIT**

try the below code , it wraps the spans in another span

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.protein').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var html = el.html();
    var result = "";

    var split_by_space = html.split(" ");
    var split_by_space_length = split_by_space.length;


    for (var i = 0; i < split_by_space_length; i++) {
      result += '<span style="display:inline-block;">';
      
      var split_by_character = split_by_space[i].split("");
      var split_by_character_length = split_by_character.length;
      for (var j = 0; j < split_by_character_length; j++) {
            result += '<span class="'+split_by_character[j]+'">'+split_by_character[j]+'</span>'
      }

      result += '</span> ';
    }

    el.html(result);
  });
});
```

```css
.s {
  color: #444;
}
.c {
  color: #e21735;
}
.r {
  color: #37a647;
}
.i {
  color: #32b9e9;
}
.p {
  color: #f85b3a;
}
.t {
  color: #084e7f;
}
.a {
  color: #c9db47;
}
.l {
  color: #e43794;
}
.e {
  color: #c749f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="protein">script scale</span>
```

Comment: i also telling about this website is in Wordpress, and i put the TITLE tag , so how can i put separate span with inline-block :)

Comment: @scriptscale so where is the wordpress tag in your  question, not putting proper tags will get you improper answers

Comment: but i put that my website is built in wordpress. and bootstrap...!!

Comment: One more thing: you we did not ad any other span or tag in class=Protein, because when we add any other add tag or class or span this will be sho in color letters. see that jQuery CODE please

Comment: NICE Work Brother (Y) its worked. see my website scriptscale.com :) thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129099/discussion-between-scriptscale-and-immortal-dude).

Answer (score 0):

since you dont provide any code you can do this

make font size of that particular element little lower

like

```
h1{
 font-size: 16px;// change size as u want
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: i put this code in mobile view area or main CSS? anyway this font-size is too much small.!! i need to show Scale in new line with this fint-size.!

Comment: i add 

`word-wrap:break-word;` but didn't solved problem, but when give `font-size:16px;` or add size for both words show in a row. so its looks good. but i need same size is 50px if you wanna see code so see from firebug this is website: scriptscale.com

Comment: can i give my website link adress in main post? for anyone view on mobile?